# View is not refreshing after post

Tags: python, django, internet-explorer, firefox

I use a simple form to edit the name of a invoice (invoice_text). When I submit the changes it redirects back to index page. The problem is that the index page is showing the old records. This is only in Firefox. Internet Explorer shows the changes directly. F5 helps, but of course it needs to show the new (edited) information.

forms.py

```
class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('Invoice_text',)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_invoice_list = Invoice.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_invoice_list': latest_invoice_list}
    return render(request, 'invoices/index.html', context)

def invoice_edit(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InvoiceForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.Invoice_text = request.POST['Invoice_text']
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/invoices/')
    else:
        form = InvoiceForm(instance=obj)
    return render(request, 'polls/edit_Invoice.html', {'form': form})
```

Index.html template

```
{% if latest_invoice_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for invoice in latest_invoice_list %}
        <li><a href="/invoices/{{ invoice.id }}/">{{ invoice.invoice_text }}</a> |  <a href="{% url 'invoice_edit' pk=invoice.pk %}">edit</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange, but you should be able to use the `@never_cache` decorator to prevent it:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def index(request):
    ....
```